# Tcl text: how to programmatically move the insertion point?

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have successfully created a tcl text object and filled it with text.
focus .textpath sets the focus, but pressing an arrow takes me to the end of the text.

how do I ensure the insertion point is at the beginning of the text without user intervention?

Comment: Something like `bind .textpath FocusIn ...`, maybe. (https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/bind.html#M18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insertion point is the `insert` mark, which defaults to having right gravity (so text inserted at the point where the mark is goes to the left of it).

To move a mark programmatically, use the `mark set` method:

```
$txt mark set $mark $position
```

The `$position` can be any valid text location descriptor, including `1.0` for the start of the text (it looks like a floating point number *but isn't;* it's `$line.$char`), `end` for the end, `1.end` for the end of the first line, etc.

In your case, to move the insertion position to the start, do this:

```
$txt mark set insert 1.0
```

Comment: another win from dkf!